# How can i change Default Splash image in coco2D?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to cocos2D.

As my title says, how can I change my default splash image?
In my project, I removed all of the **built-in images** *(splash image)* come with cocos2d when you create a project. Then I ran my app. Why do I still see the built-in image *(splash image that i removed)* when my project it started?

I tried to find my solution on google but i could not find anything useful.

So, please help me resolve this issue. It may be very useful for a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the file is called 'Default.png', and you replace it with what you want. If you've already deleted the 'Default.png' file, create a new one.

The 'Default.png' should be placed in the root.

Then Build ->Clean All Targets

Create an image 320×480 for portrait mode

Comment: Is there a splash image shown or is it just a black screen while loading?

Comment: I remove all built-in image ... so there are not any 'Default.png' image

Comment: so how built-in image , i seems even i removed it

Comment: Ok, so create an image in the root of the project called 'Default.png'

Comment: Glad I could help. All the best

Comment: you know how to change animation of splash ?? have any best link of tutorial ?

Answer (score 1):

Place the following

```
#define CC_CODE_IDE_DEBUG_SUPPORT 0
```

at

```
Appdelegate.cpp
```

Which is at

```
Framworks --. runtime-src -->classes folder
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete "Default.png" from your resources. And add an image with name Default.png which you want as Splash into your resources.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you replace all the Default files in the Resources folder with your own art. For example:

```
Default-568@2x.png
Default.png
Default@2x.png
```

Comment: "@2x" not working in coco2D... for retina display you need to apply "-hd" instad of "@2x"search on goole :) fo